# Obtain a CGContextRef of NSView outside of drawRect?

Tags: cocoa, macos, graphics, core-graphics, nsview

I need to get CGContextRef of NSView object. It won't be so bad if I knew how.

In Carbon this thing was done like this:

```
CGContextRef cgref = (libvlc_drawable_t)GetWindowPort(HIViewGetWindow((OpaqueControlRef*)hiViewRef));
```

Obviously it can be done by subclassing NSView (or it's subclass) and catching it in it's drawRect, but that's too ugly.

Your ideas?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but it sounds like something that will lead to a lot of frustration.

Comment: I'm embedding VLC video player in my application. I need a "drawable" to which it would... draw.

Answer (score 9):

I've never used it but it think this is your way:

```
[myView lockFocus];
imageContext = (CGContextRef)[[NSGraphicsContext currentContext]
                                     graphicsPort];
... 
[myView unlockFocus];
```

also have a look to the lockFocusIfCanDraw of NSView

Comment: That's what I'd do, too, but it's worth clarifying that you probably shouldn't count on that context being valid past the `unlockFocus` message.

Comment: Thought of it too, but what's interesting, that on MS Windows, I use window id, which is also supposed to be impermanent, and it works fine (see my comment in the question block)